# laravel 5 routing

Tags: javascript, laravel, route

Доброго времени суток 
В js (там календарь) получаю строку такого вида :
http://myla/tmpls/month.html?_=1436730811055
задача получить редирект на html и передать значение 
В директории resources/view/tmpls :

```
day.html  events-list.html  modal.html  month-day.html  month.html  week-days.html  week.html  year.html  year-month.html
```

Подскажите как прописать routes

```
Route::get('nomer/tmpls/{any}',function($any){
    Return View::make('tmpls.any');
});
```

В таком виде не работает.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то вот так

```
Route::get('nomer/tmpls/{any}',function($any){
    Return View::make('tmpls.'.$any);
});
```